# Inverse image of ideal under inclusion

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm interested in considering two commutative rings with unit $R$ and $S$ with an inclusion morphism $i: R \hookrightarrow S$.  Let $m \subset R$ be a maximal ideal in $R$.  Now I know that the image of $m$ under the inclusion need not even be an ideal in $S$, much less maximal.  However, I've read that the ideal $i(m) \cdot S$ is sort of a canonical ideal in $S$ recovered from the image of $m$.  This much makes sense to me.

So in the setting of algebraic geometry, we're interested in taking inverse images of ideals by ring morphisms.  So I'm wondering, will the inverse image of $i(m) \cdot S$ be simply the maximal ideal $m \subset R$?  If not, is there a canonical way, given a maximal ideal in $R$, to find an ideal in $S$ whose inverse image is the original maximal ideal?

If the context helps, I'm ultimately thinking in the algebraic geometry setting where the rings will be affine coordinate rings, and the inverse images of ideals will define the associated morphisms of affine varieties.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: That construction is called the *extension* of $m$ to $S$ (usually denoted by $mS$). If you are lucky and $mS\ne S$, then the inverse image of $mS$ equals $m$.

Comment: Thanks!  So the condition $mS \neq S$ is all one needs to ensure the inverse image recovers $m$?  Indeed, in my case, I think I can definitely ensure that equality is not satisfied

Comment: Yes, that's the only condition since $m\subseteq mS\cap R\subseteq R$, and $mS\cap R=R$ iff $1\in mS$.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks a lot.  This argument uses that my ring morphism is specifically an inclusion it seems?  Which makes sense because this shouldn't work out this well for an arbitrary ring morphism.  I believe what this implies is that an injective ring morphism gives rise to a surjective corresponding morphism of affine varieties.